# Unable to use apache hama(install) on ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, installation, hama

**This is the configuration file I have(hama-site):**

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>bsp.master.address</name>
<value>local</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000/</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hama.zookeeper.quorum</name>
<value>localhost</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

I have already started HDFS.
and I also tried to add the zookeeper port property after installing the zookeeper on local.

**After the above configuration I tried to execute the /bin/start-bspd.sh script and it shows following error:**

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hama.zookeeper.ZKServerTool
starting bspmaster, logging to /opt/hama-0.6.2/bin/../logs/hama-diplav-bspmaster-cloud.out
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hama.BSPMasterRunner
localhost: starting groom, logging to /opt/hama-0.6.2/bin/../logs/hama-diplav-groom-cloud.out
localhost: Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hama.GroomServerRunner
```

Comment: which version of the hadoop you are using?